# Is it possible to disable specific, core, SQL statements?

Tags: mysql

I can disable stored procedures, trigger, etc in MySQL.

I also want to disable some SQL statements that aren't used in the application that uses MySQL (e.g: UNION); similar to PHP's `disable_function`.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? You're just going to confuse and annoy future developers. If you're worried about potential attack vectors then this is not going to help. By the time someone can execute SQL directly on your database you're already compromised.

Comment: Instead of [telling us the solution you've decided to use](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), first tell us what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: [disable_functions](http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions) for anyone wondering

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot disable certain keywords in SQL. MySQL has no feature analogous to PHP's `disable_function`.

You can restrict the operations a user can do by limiting which [SQL privileges](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant.html#grant-privileges) you grant to that user. But there is no distinct privilege for `UNION`. If the user can `SELECT`, they can use `UNION`.

You haven't stated what problem you're trying to solve. I suspect you're trying to solve SQL injection, because UNION-based SQL injection attacks are well known.

But if this is the case, you're solving it wrong. You should just use proper escaping or parameterization, and that will solve most cases of SQL injection vulnerabilities. Sorry, but this is likely going to require that you do a code inspection and some code editing.